# BackupExec Hyper-V availability (within BackupExec 2010 or seperate?)

Tags: backupexec

I have downloaded the trial of Symantec BackupExec 2010 but I am a little confused: The agent for Hyper-V is available and for sale ($1800 or something), but the trial of BackupExec tells me i can install the agents I need from the installer.

Can I install a full version of BackupExec, providing I have the license, but also install a full version of the Hyper-V agent? Or do I have to download/buy this seperately? Is a trial version available for the agents?

As is probably obvious from this thread, I am a bit confused about the business model of this product. Please clarify.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

During the trial period you can install and use all of the options and agents. Once the trial period ends then any components you haven't added a license for will cease to function.

Comment: Yep and to clarify - When it comes to the actual purchase you need to buy the Backup Exec product itself PLUS the separate Hyper-V Agents for your hosts. You then add the license numbers into the backup exec console, and the corresponding number of agent installations are enabled.